# puppet file protocol handle throws Could not evaluate

Tags: puppet

Error: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/]: `Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/rpm/ssldump-0.9-0.9.b3.el6.x86_64.rpm`

```
[fedora@puppet puppet]$ tree
.
├── auth.conf
├── autosign.conf
├── environments
│   └── example_env
│       ├── manifests
│       ├── modules
│       └── README.environment
├── fileserver.conf
├── manifests
│   └── site.pp
├── modules
│   └── rpm
│       └── ntp3.el6.x86_64.rpm
└── puppet.conf
```

Here is my site.pp

```
file { "/opt/":
  ensure  => file,
  source  => "puppet:///modules/rpm/ssldump-0.9-0.9.b3.el6.x86_64.rpm",
  backup  => false,

}
```

On the Puppet Agent node it's throws the error

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/rpm/ssldump-0.9-0.9.b3.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved by placing the files in the files server direcoty

```
.
└── files
    └── ntp3.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

followed the [video](https://goo.gl/C9DeLb)  to help me get the problem solved

```
.
└── rpm
    └── files
        └── ntp3.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the documentation about [the puppet file server](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html#the-puppet-file-server).

According to the example:

```
puppet:///modules/test_module/testfile.txt
```

> …will resolve to the following absolute path:

```
/etc/puppet/modules/test_module/files/testfile.txt
```

When you are using puppet protocol to server files, it always automatically resolves `files/` directory.

Additional reading about module structure [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_fundamentals.html#module-layout).